# DATEDIFF() for dynamically changing dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to solve a problem with finding the amount of days between two dates that are always changing.
I have a field in my dataset called created_at. This is the date that a push notification is sent out to users. I am looking at the 30 days before and after a notification is sent out. This I do by:

```
WHERE DATE > DATE_SUB(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND DATE < DATE_ADD(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Now I am looking at using the DATE_DIFF function to juxtapose these two dates but I am having some issues. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
(Using BigQuery/Periscope)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What are the two dates?  You have only described one of them.

Comment: The two dates are 30 days before and 30 days after a notification has been sent. So I'm looking at getting the amount of days from a notification is sent to I can see user activity.

Comment: 30 days before and 30 days after will be 61 days - right? so something really missing in your question. can you elaborate / provide more details?

Comment: I used Gordons answer it worked. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number of days between two timestamps then use `timestamp_diff()`:

```
select timestamp_diff(notification_ts, created_ts, day)
```

This assumes that the columns are `timestamps`.  Similar functions exist for `datetime`s and `date`s.